# Install ubuntu 16.04 in HP 14-am006ns

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

First of all, I do not have a problem, I just need some information.
I have been reading a lot of information about dual boot of W10 and ubuntu 16.04 in UEFI and how to fix boot problems using windows and ubuntu tools. I think I am ready to install it and I am going to buy an HP 14-AM006NS to do the installation. 
I have seen on internet that some HP laptops with W10 only can boot Windows, and the UEFI can not be configured to boot something else.
I do not know if this is true and have not been able to figure out because HP support does not let me open a question without a SN.
¿ Has anybody done the installation of ubuntu 16.04 in UEFI mode on this machine ?

Answer (score 3):

According to the official Ubuntu Site, installing Ubuntu on this machine should not be a problem, but if you run into problems, you might need to disable Secure Boot, shut down Windows Completely instead of just rebooting, and maybe you also need to enable the Legacy Mode.

https://certification.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201406-15267/

I guess this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Note that Ubuntu certified hardware is certified with Ubuntu running as the *only* OS on the computer; no testing is done of dual-boot configurations. Thus, problems with dual-boot setups can slip through. Such problems can usually be worked around, but doing so can sometimes be awkward. I recommend upgrading to the latest firmware (what most manufacturers call a "BIOS") before installing Ubuntu. See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/) for more general advice.

Comment: First of all, Thanks to rod smith, http://askubuntu.com/users/93977/rod-smith,   for your advise and of course I read your pages about dual boot.
After doing a disk image with clonezilla live USB, and testing the Ubuntu 16.04 live, and setting up W10,  Clonezilla gave me an error saying the this was dirty.
I had to recover w10 from the recovery partition.
I do not know if the dirty disk problem was caused by:
Clonezilla live,
Ubuntu 16.04 live or
Errors in the factory version of windows 10.

 In the meantime I am thinking whether to do the dual boot Ubuntu + W10 or not.